# nginx: autoindex with basic auth

Tags: nginx, http-basic-authentication

I have a running website where I have a specific directory where I store random stuff (it sounds very informal and it indeed is).

So, I wanted to have some sort of index there that lists the contents of that directory (and subdirectories). `autoindex` would work perfectly.

Then, I don't really want others to browse that index. `auth_basic` would work perfectly.

But, I'd like to be able to link to specific files or directories inside that directory (that is a directory that **does** contain an index file and not an *autoindex*) without having them password protected.

So, the final idea would be to have a location with *autoindices* that are password protected with **basic auth** but leaving the rest of the files and directories untouched.

I came up with a hacky solution **that works**: since an HTTP status 403 is issued when an index that does not exist is accessed, I redirect that to a custom `location` block that enables `autoindex` with `auth_basic`.

See here an example:

```
server {
    root ...;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name ...;
    access_log ...;
    error_log ...;

    # general site
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
        location ~ \.php(/|$) {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm-....sock;
        }
    }

    # rewrite for the general site
    /location @rewrite {
        rewrite ...;
    }

    # that specific directory
    location /directory {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        error_page 403 = @autoindex; # hack 1

        location ~ \.php(/|$) {
            # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            try_files $uri $uri/;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm-....sock;
        }
    }
    
    # password-protected autoindices
    location @autoindex {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        auth_basic "directory";
        auth_basic_user_file /.../.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

So... is there a better idea? Is this hack a bad idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So, the final idea would be to have a location with autoindices that are password protected with basic auth but leaving the rest of the files and directories untouched.

Try using regex `location` to specify any locations you need to protect with `basic_auth`.

Prefix-based `location` will [always checked first, but used last, after all](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) regex-based `location` checked. If no regex-based `location` matches current request, longest-matching prefix-based `location` will be used.

Here, you can do something like

```
index index.html;

location ~ /directory(/$|$) { # http://example.com/directory, http://example.com/directory/
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    auth_basic "directory";
    auth_basic_user_file /.../.htpasswd;
}

location /directory { # http://example.com/directory/favicon.ico
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm-....sock;
    }
}
```

Using `http://example.com` as your base URL:

- any requests to `http://example.com/directory` and `http://example.com/directory/` will be `autoindex`-ed and having `auth_basic` enabled, according to `location ~ /directory(/$|$)` directive.
- any other requests to `http://example.com/directory/*` will be served according to `location /directory` directive.

Comment: Aha, but what about requests to `http;//example.com/directory/inner/`? I'd like to have those _autoindex_ed.
And then, what would happen if `http://example.com/directory/other/` does have an `index.html` file? I'd like that to be served. Thanks!

Comment: would specifying the directories manually suffice, e.g. `location ~ /(directory|directory/inner)(/$|$) {`? and any directories with `index.html`, as long as `index` directive is set with `index.html` and regex-based location doesn't include the directory, its `index.html` will be served.